# Can't get session to save/persist on deployed express server

Tags: node.js, express, firebase-hosting, express-session, google-cloud-run

My attempts at logging in are not getting saved to express session in production. I am saving the session in Mongo Store and the sessions are coming up in MongoAtlas as modified (they way they should appear), but for some reason the server is not recognizing that there is an existing session and is making a new one. When I enable express-session debug, it logs `express-session no SID sent, generating session` on each request to the server. This makes me think that the session id isn't getting sent with the request and that the problem has something to do with my client and server being on different domains (my client address is `https://example.com` and my server is on `https://app.example.com`. I originally had my client on `https://www.example.com` but changed it thinking that the cookie was getting mistaken for a 3rd party cookie (maybe it still is).

My client is hosted on Firebase Hosting and my Express server is hosted on Google Cloud Run

my express-session settings

```
app.set('trust proxy', true)
app.use(session({
   secret: 'myappisasecret', 
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: false,
   secure: true,
   store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection}),
   cookie: {
       maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
       sameSite: 'lax',
       secure: true,
       domain: 'mysite.com'
   },
   proxy: true // I think this makes the trust proxy be useless 
}))
```

Below is my coors server stuff. This code is located above the code above, but I don't think it is causing any issues, but think that it might be important to include.

```
let whitelist = ['https://app.example.com', 'https://www.example.com', 'https://example.web.app', 'https://example.com']
let corsOptions = {
   origin: (origin, callback) => {
       if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || origin === undefined) {
           callback(null, true)
       } else {
           console.log('Request Origin blocked: ', origin)
           callback(new Error('Request blocked by CORS'))
       }
   },
   credentials: true
}
 
 
app.use(cookieParser('myappisasecret'))
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Since the server wasn't receiving a session id, I thought that maybe my client wasn't sending one so I added `credentials: 'include'` to my client request code

```
const reqHeaders = {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            credentials: 'include' as any,
            method: "GET"
        }
fetch('https://app.example.com/u/loggedIn', reqHeaders)
        .then(res => etc...
```

When this request gets submitted expression-session debug logs:
`express-session saving z3ndMizKoxivXR0N9LBZYkPhDG65uvF2` and then
`express-session split response`

This makes me think that as it tries to save my user data to the session, it gets overwritten at the same time with an initial session data. I have set `resave: false`. But even then I still get `express-session no SID sent` with every request sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when hosting with Firebase and Cloud Run cookie headers get stripped due to Google's CDN cache behavior.

Here's the documentation that describes that:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/manage-cache#using_cookies

I have no clue how to implement sessions now. F